# I want to display specific item in array JSON

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swiftui

I'm pretty new to SWIFT, especially parsing JSON I want to display specific item from array in my friend's JSON API.

I have this API url: https://api.novella-designer.com/api/:version/tree/preview/307ea989-a7aa-4496-a86e-0577cec10754

My problem is, I can't display one specific item from that array, here's my JSON decoding file:

```
import Foundation

@MainActor

class JsonNovella: ObservableObject {
    
    private struct Returned: Codable {
        var slides: [Slides]
        var status: String
    }
    
    struct Slides: Codable, Hashable {
        var slide: Slide
        
    }
    
    struct Slide: Codable, Hashable {
        var action: [Action]
        var id: String
    }
    
    struct Action: Codable, Hashable{
        var name: String
        var map_action: MapAction
    }
    
    
    struct MapAction: Codable, Hashable{
        var transaction_elements: [TransitionElements]?
    }
    
    struct TransitionElements: Codable, Hashable{
        var component_map: ComponentMap?
    }
    
    struct ComponentMap: Codable, Hashable{
      var elements: [Elements]
    }
    
    struct Elements: Codable, Hashable{
        var color: String
        var name: String
        var image_url: String?
        var type: String
        var text: String?
    }
    
    @Published var urlString = "https://api.novella-designer.com/api/:version/tree/preview/307ea989-a7aa-4496-a86e-0577cec10754"
    @Published var slides: [Slides] = []
    @Published var status = ""
    
    
    
    func getData() async {
        print("We are accessing the url \(urlString)")
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("ERROR: could not create URL from \(urlString)")
            return
        }
        do  {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            guard  let returned = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Returned.self, from: data) else {
                print("ERROR: could not decode data  from \(urlString)")
                return
            }
            
            self.status = returned.status
            self.slides = returned.slides
            print(returned.slides)
            
        } catch {
            print("ERROR: could not get data  from \(urlString)")
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my SWIFTUI file, I don't actually know, if im doing right. I've watched a lot of videos about parsing JSON, but couldn't find the solution for me.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct NovellaViewer: View {
    var loop = 5

    @StateObject var novellaJS = JsonNovella()
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView() {
            VStack{
                ForEach(novellaJS.slides, id: \.self) { slides in

                    
                    ZStack{
                        ForEach(slides.slide.action, id: \.self){ slide in
                            ForEach(slide.map_action.transaction_elements ?? [], id: \.self) { slide in
                                ForEach(slide.component_map?.elements ?? [], id: \.self) { slide in
                                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: slide.image_url ?? "")) { phase in
                                            if let image = phase.image{
                                                image
                                                    .resizable()
                                                    .scaledToFit()
                                            }
                                        }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .task {
              await  novellaJS.getData()
        }
        }
    }
}


#Preview{
    NovellaViewer()
}
```

I've tried to select item from array like using [1], but it doesn't work for me, I guess, this because it's JSON, not just array. So I want to have call 1-2 objects from array, just to make character and background behind him.

Can somebody at least give me some info or links. Because im literally spend a week on it.

Comment: I think you've made the situation much more complicated with your naming. For example, you have something called `Slides` (plural) which only contains one `Slide` (singular). You've also just said "doesn't work" but it's unclear if the code doesn't compile, it gives a runtime error, etc. I'd suggest pasting your JSON into app.quicktype.io and using the models that site generates

Comment: I mean, all my json is showing, my problem is that I can't get only one item from array. Like I can't write for example " .first or use [5]".

Comment: I agree with @jnpdx. Consolidate the naming. There are 3 `ForEach` expressions, all with `slide` as loop element which is confusing, maybe even for the compiler.

Comment: @Kancey You haven't shown any attempts at using `first` or accessing by index, so it's hard to say what's going wrong

Comment: Maybe in your `JsonNovella` object, rather than using the property `@Published var slides: [Slides] = []`, make a property like `@Published var slideToDisplay: Slides?`, then inside your `getData` function, assign only one value to this property using `returned.slides.first`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all of the `id: \.self` that is a violation of the `ForEach` API where the `id` param must be a unique identifier of the data it cannot be the data itself.

Best conform `Slide` to `Identifiable`, make a `var id` then it will work with `ForEach` with no `id` param required.

`class JsonNovella: ObservableObject` needs to be removed or at least not be `@MainActor`. Since you are using async/await and not Combine it is best to just remove that class and do this:

```
.task {
    slides = await novellaJS.getData()
}
```

Where slides is `@State` and `novellaJS` is a controller in an `EnvironmentKey`.

Answer (score 0):

`...I can't display one specific item from that array...`

To get a specific `item`, for example the first image url from your models,
you need to go through the different model structures dealing with possible `Optional`
values (I use `if let ...`) and assign it to a var (eg: `firstUrl`).

The working example code shows how to display the first image you get from the server (red border),
using `func getFirstUrl()` or alternatively `func getFirstUrl2()`

Note, you should take the advice regarding naming of models, and use `Identifiable` when needed.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NovellaViewer()
    }
}

@MainActor
class JsonNovella: ObservableObject {
    
    private struct Returned: Codable {
        var slides: [Slides]
        var status: String
    }
    
    struct Slides: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {  // <-- here
        let id = UUID()  // <-- here
        var slide: Slide
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {   // <-- here
            case slide
        }
    }
    
    struct Slide: Codable, Hashable {
        var action: [Action]
        var id: String
    }
    
    struct Action: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {  // <-- here
        let id = UUID()  // <-- here
        var name: String
        var map_action: MapAction
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {   // <-- here
            case name, map_action
        }
    }
    
    struct MapAction: Codable, Hashable{
        var transaction_elements: [TransitionElements]?
    }
    
    struct TransitionElements: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {  // <-- here
        let id = UUID()  // <-- here
        var component_map: ComponentMap?
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {   // <-- here
            case component_map
        }
    }
    
    struct ComponentMap: Codable, Hashable{
        var elements: [Elements]
    }
    
    struct Elements: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {  // <-- here
        let id = UUID()  // <-- here
        var color: String
        var name: String
        var image_url: String?
        var type: String
        var text: String?
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {   // <-- here
            case color,name,image_url,type, text
        }
    }
    
    @Published var urlString = "https://api.novella-designer.com/api/:version/tree/preview/307ea989-a7aa-4496-a86e-0577cec10754"
    @Published var slides: [Slides] = []
    @Published var status = ""
    
    
    func getData() async {
        print("---> We are accessing the url \(urlString)")
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("ERROR: could not create URL from \(urlString)")
            return
        }
        do  {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let returned = try JSONDecoder().decode(Returned.self, from: data)  // <-- here
            self.status = returned.status
            self.slides = returned.slides
        } catch {
            print("---> ERROR: \(error)") // <-- important
        }
    }
    
}

struct NovellaViewer: View {
    @StateObject var novellaJS = JsonNovella()
    @State var firstUrl: URL?  // <--- here, for testing
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            // to display the first image for testing
            AsyncImage(url: firstUrl) { phase in
                if let image = phase.image {
                    image.resizable().scaledToFit()
                }
            }.border(.red, width: 6)
            
            Divider()
            
            ScrollView() {
                ForEach(novellaJS.slides) { slides in   // <-- here etc...
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(slides.slide.action) { slide in
                            ForEach(slide.map_action.transaction_elements ?? []) { trans in
                                ForEach(trans.component_map?.elements ?? []) { item in
                                    AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item.image_url ?? "")) { phase in
                                        if let image = phase.image {
                                            image.resizable().scaledToFit()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await novellaJS.getData()
            getFirstUrl() // <-- here
        }
    }
    
    // the function to retrieve the first `item.image_url` from your models
    func getFirstUrl() {
    outerloop:
        for slides in novellaJS.slides {
            for action in slides.slide.action {
                if let elements = action.map_action.transaction_elements {
                    for trans in elements {
                        if let compMap = trans.component_map {
                            for item in compMap.elements  {
                                if let url = item.image_url {
                                    firstUrl = URL(string: url)
                                    break outerloop
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

// alternative using index into the various arrays,
// and dealing with optionals, and index out-of-range prevention
func getFirstUrl2() {
    if novellaJS.slides.count > 0 {
        let actions = novellaJS.slides[0].slide.action
        if actions.count > 1 {
            if let elements = actions[1].map_action.transaction_elements, elements.count > 0  {
                if let compMap = elements[0].component_map, compMap.elements.count > 0  {
                    let item = compMap.elements[0]
                    if let url = item.image_url {
                        firstUrl = URL(string: url)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
    
}
```